# Varnish enabled or not?

Tags: magento2, cache, configuration, full-page-cache, varnish

Hi dears I installed varnish cache on centos 7 , nginx `1.20.1` and magento `2.4.5 -p1`.

After that I don't seeing any header about varnish on my browser.

Another thing when I clear cache I have log in varnishlog.

Just I have `x-magento-debug :1` did I installed successfully ?

**I tested it in developer mode**

```
    *   << Request  >> 65563
-   Begin          req 65560 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1669538667.505033 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1669538667.505033 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       217.218.39.33 56922 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Host: oursite
-   ReqHeader      Connection: keep-alive
-   ReqHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=0
-   ReqHeader      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8,de;q=0.7
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.402651066.1669532827; _gid=GA1.2.913114647.1669532827; AMCVS_8F99160E571FC0427F000101%40AdobeOrg=1; AMCV_8F99160E571FC0427F000101%40AdobeOrg=-1124106680%7CMCIDTS%7C19324%7CMCMID%7C21125325410411075930590493714775457981%7CMCAAMLH-1670138
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 217.218.39.33
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqUnset       Host: oursite
-   ReqHeader      Host: oursite
-   ReqURL         /
-   VCL_return     hash
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   HitMiss        65556 51.242489
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 65564 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1669538668.060497 0.555464 0.555464
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     200
-   RespReason     OK
-   RespHeader     Server: nginx/1.20.1
-   RespHeader     Date: Sun, 27 Nov 2022 08:44:28 GMT
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   RespHeader     X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.33
-   RespHeader     Set-Cookie: mage-cache-sessid=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; secure; SameSite=None
-   RespHeader     Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=eceligmlkvgt7k80ngqj4gior2; expires=Sun, 27-Nov-2022 09:44:27 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=oursite; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
-   RespHeader     Expires: Sat, 27 Nov 2021 08:44:27 GMT
-   RespHeader     X-Magento-Debug: 1
-   RespHeader     Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: font-src *.fontawesome.com data: 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; form-action 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-ancestors 'self'; frame-src fast.amc.demdex.net *.adobe.com bid.g.doubleclick.net *.youtube.com *.youtube-nocookie.com
-   RespHeader     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
-   RespHeader     X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
-   RespHeader     X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   RespHeader     X-Magento-Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
-   RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 65563
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.6)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespHeader     X-Magento-Cache-Debug: UNCACHEABLE
-   RespUnset      Pragma: no-cache
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespUnset      Expires: Sat, 27 Nov 2021 08:44:27 GMT
-   RespHeader     Expires: -1
-   RespUnset      Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
-   RespUnset      X-Magento-Debug: 1
-   RespUnset      X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.33
-   RespUnset      Server: nginx/1.20.1
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 65563
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.6)
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1669538668.060581 0.555548 0.000084
-   Filters
-   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 28145
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1669538668.061301 0.556268 0.000720
-   ReqAcct        1419 0 1419 2420 28145 30565
-   End
**  << BeReq    >> 65564
--  Begin          bereq 65563 fetch
--  VCL_use        boot
--  Timestamp      Start: 1669538667.505333 0.000000 0.000000
--  BereqMethod    GET
--  BereqURL       /
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
--  BereqHeader    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
--  BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
--  BereqHeader    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8,de;q=0.7
--  BereqHeader    Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.402651066.1669532827; _gid=GA1.2.913114647.1669532827; AMCVS_8F99160E571FC0427F000101%40AdobeOrg=1; AMCV_8F99160E571FC0427F000101%40AdobeOrg=-1124106680%7CMCIDTS%7C19324%7CMCMID%7C21125325410411075930590493714775457981%7CMCAAMLH-1670138
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 217.218.39.33
--  BereqHeader    Host: oursite
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
--  BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 65564
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  Timestamp      Fetch: 1669538667.505422 0.000089 0.000089
--  Timestamp      Connected: 1669538667.505432 0.000099 0.000010
--  BackendOpen    34 default 127.0.0.1 8080 127.0.0.1 38448 reuse
--  Timestamp      Bereq: 1669538667.505585 0.000251 0.000152
--  Timestamp      Beresp: 1669538668.046902 0.541568 0.541317
--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
--  BerespStatus   200
--  BerespReason   OK
--  BerespHeader   Server: nginx/1.20.1
--  BerespHeader   Date: Sun, 27 Nov 2022 08:44:28 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
--  BerespHeader   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
--  BerespHeader   Connection: keep-alive
--  BerespHeader   X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.33
--  BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: mage-cache-sessid=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; secure; SameSite=None
--  BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=eceligmlkvgt7k80ngqj4gior2; expires=Sun, 27-Nov-2022 09:44:27 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=oursite; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
--  BerespHeader   Pragma: no-cache
--  BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
--  BerespHeader   Expires: Sat, 27 Nov 2021 08:44:27 GMT
--  BerespHeader   X-Magento-Debug: 1
--  BerespHeader   Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: font-src *.fontawesome.com data: 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; form-action 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-ancestors 'self'; frame-src fast.amc.demdex.net *.adobe.com bid.g.doubleclick.net *.youtube.com *.youtube-nocookie.com
--  BerespHeader   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
--  BerespHeader   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
--  BerespHeader   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
--  BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
--  BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding
--  TTL            RFC 0 10 0 1669538668 1669538668 1669538668 1638002667 0 cacheable
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
--  TTL            VCL 0 259200 0 1669538668 cacheable
--  BerespHeader   X-Magento-Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
--  TTL            VCL 120 259200 0 1669538668 cacheable
--  TTL            VCL 120 259200 0 1669538668 uncacheable
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  Timestamp      Process: 1669538668.046969 0.541635 0.000066
--  Filters         gunzip esi_gzip
--  BerespUnset    Content-Encoding: gzip
--  BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
--  Storage        malloc Transient
--  Fetch_Body     2 chunked -
--  Gzip           G F E 190843 28145 80 225080 225090
--  Gzip           U F - 28120 190843 80 224880 224890
--  BackendClose   34 default recycle
--  Timestamp      BerespBody: 1669538668.060481 0.555148 0.013512
--  Length         28145
--  BereqAcct      1410 0 1410 2381 28120 30501
--  End
```

Comment: please help me!

Answer (score 0):

First, did you start the varnish service:

service varnish start

If Varnish fails to start as a service, start it from the command line as follows:

Start the Varnish CLI:

```
varnishd -d -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

Start the Varnish child process:

When prompted, enter start

The following messages display to confirm a successful start:

child (29805) Started
200 0

Child (29805) said
Child (29805) said Child starts

**To Verify HTTP Header Response**

There are several ways to look at response headers, including using a browser plug-in or a browser inspector.

The following example uses curl. You can enter this command from any machine that can access the Magento server using HTTP.

```
curl -I -v --location-trusted '<your Magento base URL>'
```

For example,

```
curl -I -v --location-trusted 'http://192.0.2.55/magento2'
```

Look for headers like the following:

Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
X-Varnish: 15
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish-v6
X-Magento-Cache-Debug: HIT

Thanks

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer 
varnish started and i haven't error on log 
but when i get curl show below :
< HTTP/1.1 503 Backend fetch failed
HTTP/1.1 503 Backend fetch failed
< Retry-After: 5
Retry-After: 5
< X-Magento-Cache-Debug: MISS
X-Magento-Cache-Debug: MISS
< Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: -1
Expires: -1
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: and my backend works well

Comment: Error: Varnishd is already running (pid=5918) (pidfile=/var/lib/varnish/localhost//_.pid)